# jquery geocomplete - getting users current location name

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

We are currently using the following jquery plugin for dropdown geo-autocomplete on a text input and it works well:
http://ubilabs.github.io/geocomplete/

What we want to do however is show the users current default location in that input box before they type/select anything. Eg: Los Angeles or Sydney or London. Similar to how Facebook shows the local city name next to the map marker (which you can then click on to change it to something else)

Example of what I mean: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcrRs.png
(Sorry I can't paste the image in-line as <10 rep points)

Is something like this possible with the jquery geocomplete plugin or Google Maps API's Geocoding and Places Autocomplete services?

Thanks!

Comment: I've a query. I've also used this plugin http://ubilabs.github.io/geocomplete/ . Is it free? Or there is any request limit each day? Can you please tell me?

Answer (score 2):

You will want to combine https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation.getCurrentPosition

with the google places api

HTML - Loads the google places library:

```
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=true"></script>
<div id="google"></div>
...
```

Js:

```
...
if (navigator.geolocation) {
         navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(addressToCode);
}

addressToCode = function (position,callback) {

        var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(document.getElementById('google'));
        var request = { query: new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude) }
        service.textSearch(request, function (json, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
              //RESULTS -- DO SOMETHING HERE 
              json[0].name;
            } else {
                //alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + json.status);
            }
        });
};
...
```

I mentioned the GeoCoding Api, which I have had serious api limit issues with, but for reference, here is the code:

NO HTML NEEDED

JS:

```
  addressToCode = function (position) {
        var url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude + "&sensor=false";
        $.getJSON(url, function (json) {
            if (json.status == 'OK') {
                //DO SOMTHING HERE
                json.results[0].formatted_address;
            } else {
                //alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + json.status);
            }
        });
};
```

Comment: Thanks much Chris, I will give it a try later.
Can you explain the purpose of the empty Google div and should it be empty? used here:
var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(document.getElementById('google'));

Comment: This seems to return the street number/name, rather than the local city/townname - which is what we want to return. Is that possible? Thanks Chris!

Comment: The places api requires a dom element to bind to, that the only reason for the empty div.

Comment: The places api requires a dom element to bind to, that the only reason for the empty div. One of the properties that is returned is the formatted address. This will have the city. You may need to process the string a little to get the exact info you need. Technically the GeoCoding api works better for this, but I found that you can QUICKLY hit the api limits and I highly recommend not using it.